# Where to escalate video support for Blender

Tags: video

Where may I escalate continuing video issues with Blender? I don't have the "status" to make a bug report.

Blender's continuing problems with video support is disqualifying. The latest release of Blender had already refused to work on three of my four machines. Only one laptop was able to run Blender at all, and then only after reverting to v2.81.

This laptop ran blender fine until last night. Today Blender wont boot and generates the all too familiar "Blender requires OGL 3.3 to run...". The last box to die has OGL4.0 and Direct X 11.

Yes, all of my boxes meet the stated video/hardware requirements, have current drivers, and OGL exceeding 3.3. It's a real problem that the only support for video problems is to parrot the OGL3.3/current drivers advice. While helpful for a few beginners, it is clear that Blender has video issues beyond currency.

Is there a contact available to deal with Blender's persistent video problems directly?

Thanks.

[image: Terminal message]

Comment: This site is not associated with the developers,  so this is definitely not the place to report bugs.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: BTW everybody can report bugs on the bug tracker, you only need an account.

Comment: Also please make sure that your system fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender, in particular check that your GPUs are supported. If you have both an integrated GPU and dedicated GPU, you need to verify the requirements for both. On Windows you can select which one is used to start Blender in the Graphics Settings (see [T78799](https://developer.blender.org/T78799)).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but: I indicated that my systems all meet the stated minimum requirements. The last system to stop running it has been running for 3 months with minimal problems. No GPU here, running on laptop Intel integrated graphics, just fine till yesterday. Tried to file bug report for a different problem, and received message (paraphrasing) that I was too new to the forum. I didn't try to report the bug here, rather I went to a link provided by a commenter on the problem being discussed. Thanks.

Comment: If it worked fine before and suddenly doesn't anymore the most likely culprit is an automated update of the OS or drivers. It seems you haven't reported the issue on the official bug tracker, but rather some community forum. The bug tracker can be found here: https://developer.blender.org

Comment: What CPU and integrated GPU is in your laptop and what is the driver version that you're using?

Comment: After trying six different drivers, and working with Intel support for three hours, with no luck, I made some progress. First, I downloaded an update to the Opengl3.2.DLL, which allowed the .exe to run only from within the install directory...but not from a desktop shortcut. I then discovered that running from the desktop shortcut works by right clicking and running as Administrator. My account is already an administrator. Any suggestions why that is happening? I recently "upgraded" to win10 v2004, and something got changed.

Comment: I've seen your [ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T80147) on the bug tracker and replied to it. Being an administrator doesn't mean that the software is run with administrative privileges. However, this shouldn't be necessary to run Blender. Let's continue the investigation on the bug tracker.